# While loop for button press in Python (graphics.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics

Problem with finding a solution for this loop. So the project is a countdown timer and it only works once, then refuses to work again. I'm using graphics.py extension, and am trying to make it do something when a button is pressed, then when I press it again it loops back up and restarts. I've got the first part, as follows, but cant figure out the loop back part.

```
while True:
    try:
        point = win.checkMouse()
    except GraphicsError:
        return

    if point == None:
        continue
    if is_clicked(point, start_button):
        start_time = user_entry.getText()
        seq = ("0", start_time)

        if start_time[0] != '0':
            start_time = ''.join(seq)

        start_seconds = convert_to_seconds(start_time)
        for second in range(start_seconds, -1, -1):
            clock_time = convert_to_clock(second)
            clock.setText(clock_time)
            sleep(1)
        flash(win, 5)


    elif is_clicked(point, exit_button):
        win.close()
        return
    else:
        win.setBackground('red')
        sleep(.2)
        win.setBackground('white')
```

Answer (score -1):

hard to help without seeing all of the other functions, try adding if statements to is_clicked(point, start_